# not able to communicate with the client using ssh

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I am trying to setup a Hadoop cluster but i am unable to access the slave machine using ssh, though i am able to ssh to the localhost.i have tried the passphraseless method.i am totally new to Hadoop and haven't used ssh before so not able to figure out my mistake.
    Whenever i issue ssh for the client it asks me to enter the client machine's password.but as soon as i give the password i get the following line on the terminal - 
    "Permission denied, please try again"
    Also when i try to copy the public key from the master to the slave i get the same message.
    Need some help badly...

Comment: Is the username on your local machine the same as the username of the account you are trying to log in to on your cluster?

Comment: yes David..both are same

Comment: Just so that everything is completely clear, can you add exact copies of the commands you are typing and the responses you are receiving to the question? Also, try `ssh` with the `-v` flag to get more details on what `ssh` is doing.

Comment: At first i typed ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""...and got the following output- Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa):...at this point i just hit enter without specifying any file name and got this - Your identification has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
9b:82:ea:58:b4:e0:35:d7:ff:19:66:a6:c8:b3:60:7a hadoop@ubuntu
The key's randomart image is:...and the key image...and when i used -v flag i got "debug1: Next authentication method: password"

Comment: ...this was the last line i got in response to the -v flag..after that when i entered the password i got the same line again i.e Permission denied, please try again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
 Please check if ssh server is running or not? If yes, open /etc/ssh/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Issue is server is running on different port and client is pointing to different port. Before this please ensure that openssh-server and client are installed.

Vivek

Comment: Thanks for the info vivek..server is running on the machine..I'll check for the port configuration.